# Asp.net Page Breaking when %20 at the end

Tags: c#, asp.net

Basically:

```
http://localhost:53586/search/cole%20and%20son%20wallpaper%20  -- Does not work.

Says  : The resource cannot be found.
```

However this works fine:

```
http://localhost:53586/search/cole%20and%20son%20wallpaper
```

Any idea what is going on here?

Thank you

Comment: Do you expect them to point to the same thing? Then what is this thing? I would consider  a name and the same name with an  extra whitespace at the end to be different.

Comment: can you also share the point that you get the search text ? - how you get it ?

Comment: @Aristos .. its something google is generating and it breaks my page.

Comment: @Ralf both point to the same page and then the URL is broken into segment and the last is the term to search but the one with %20 never reaches the search page I can just trim if it did so that is confusing me.